# Recursive Backtracking explaination

Tags: c++, backtracking

I found source code for the N-queen puzzle and I cant wrap my head around it. I am new to recursive functions. If someone could simplify this part of the code for me and explain how this falls under backtracking. I have searched around and cant figure it out.

```
void solve(int k)
{
    if (k == N) /// We placed N-1 queens (0 included), problem solved!
    {
        ///Solution found!
        cout << "Solution: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            cout << position[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) /// Generate ALL combinations
        {
            /// Before putting a queen (the k-th queen) into a row, test it for safeness
            if (isSafe(k, i))
            {
                position[k] = i;
                /// Place another queen
                solve(k + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a more specific question, we won't solve(k+1) your homework for you.

Comment: it isnt homework i am not a Computer science student I just am interested in how this specific portion works

Comment: @Namster One good way to dig it, is stepping through with the debugger, and watch out how values are changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the algorithm works:

1. Find the next available spot for a queen on the board.  Place it there.
2. Repeat step 1 until A) you've placed `k` queens successfully or B) there are no valid placements for the queen.
3. If there are no valid placements, go back to the previous piece you placed and repeat step 1 (i.e. find a different spot for the previous queen, then try again).

You can see clearly that the backtracking occurs in step 3.  If you've reached a dead end, then keep modifying your previous piece's placement until you reach a valid solution.

Comment: So step 1 is the isSafe function. Step 2 is the recursive function. and if it there are no valid placements it goes back to the for loop?

Comment: i think the for loop is throwing me off